# Align web parts vertically in a web part zone

Tags: page-layout, content-editor-web-part, web-part-zone, cswp

I have a page layout with the web part zone. The webpart zone is supposed to have 2 webparts - CSWP and Content Editor webpart.

I need to place the CSWP above the Content Editor. I need to set the `ZoneIndex` for the webparts so that they are aligned vertically but I am unable to do so.

I have also added `Orientation="Vertical` attribute in the web part zone.

The following is my code for reference:

```
<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="spproxywebpartmanager"></WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>

    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" title="Zone 1" ID="FirstZone" width="100%" Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate>

   <spsswc:ContentBySearchWebPart runat="server" AlwaysRenderOnServer="False" ResultType="" NumberOfItems="5" ShouldHideControlWhenEmpty="False" DataProviderJSON="{&quot;SourceID&quot;:&quot;94af56ee-2b04-4331-af03-905d39db71fb&quot;,&quot;SourceName&quot;:&quot;Service News Webpart&quot;,&quot;QueryTemplate&quot;:&quot;*&quot;,&quot;ClientType&quot;:&quot;ContentSearchRegular&quot;,&quot;QueryGroupName&quot;:&quot;Default&quot;,&quot;QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl&quot;:&quot;querygroup://webroot/_catalogs/masterpage/SFWServiceNewsInstanceLandingPage.aspx?groupname=Default&quot;,&quot;IgnoreQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl&quot;:false,&quot;SourceLevel&quot;:&quot;SPSite&quot;,&quot;CollapseSpecification&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;FallbackSort&quot;:[{&quot;p&quot;:&quot;RefinableDate00&quot;,&quot;d&quot;:1}],&quot;FallbackSortJson&quot;:&quot;[{\&quot;p\&quot;:\&quot;RefinableDate00\&quot;,\&quot;d\&quot;:1}]&quot;,&quot;RankRules&quot;:null,&quot;RankRulesJson&quot;:&quot;null&quot;,&quot;AsynchronousResultRetrieval&quot;:false,&quot;SendContentBeforeQuery&quot;:true,&quot;BatchClientQuery&quot;:true,&quot;FallbackLanguage&quot;:-1,&quot;FallbackRankingModelID&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;EnableStemming&quot;:true,&quot;EnablePhonetic&quot;:false,&quot;EnableNicknames&quot;:false,&quot;EnableInterleaving&quot;:false,&quot;EnableQueryRules&quot;:true,&quot;EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty&quot;:false,&quot;HitHighlightedMultivaluePropertyLimit&quot;:-1,&quot;IgnoreContextualScope&quot;:true,&quot;ScopeResultsToCurrentSite&quot;:false,&quot;TrimDuplicates&quot;:false,&quot;Properties&quot;:{&quot;TryCache&quot;:true,&quot;Scope&quot;:&quot;{Site.URL}&quot;,&quot;UpdateLinksForCatalogItems&quot;:true,&quot;EnableStacking&quot;:true,&quot;ListId&quot;:&quot;00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&quot;},&quot;PropertiesJson&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;TryCache\&quot;:true,\&quot;Scope\&quot;:\&quot;{Site.URL}\&quot;,\&quot;UpdateLinksForCatalogItems\&quot;:true,\&quot;EnableStacking\&quot;:true,\&quot;ListId\&quot;:\&quot;00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\&quot;}&quot;,&quot;UpdateAjaxNavigate&quot;:true,&quot;SummaryLength&quot;:180,&quot;DesiredSnippetLength&quot;:90,&quot;PersonalizedQuery&quot;:false,&quot;FallbackRefinementFilters&quot;:null,&quot;IgnoreStaleServerQuery&quot;:false,&quot;RenderTemplateId&quot;:&quot;DefaultDataProvider&quot;,&quot;AlternateErrorMessage&quot;:null,&quot;Title&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" BypassResultTypes="True" ItemTemplateId="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/SFW_ServiceNewsWP_Content_Item.js" GroupTemplateId="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Group_Content.js" ResultsPerPage="5" SelectedPropertiesJson="[&quot;Title&quot;,&quot;Path&quot;,&quot;Description&quot;,&quot;EditorOWSUSER&quot;,&quot;LastModifiedTime&quot;,&quot;CollapsingStatus&quot;,&quot;DocId&quot;,&quot;HitHighlightedSummary&quot;,&quot;HitHighlightedProperties&quot;,&quot;FileExtension&quot;,&quot;ViewsLifeTime&quot;,&quot;ParentLink&quot;,&quot;FileType&quot;,&quot;IsContainer&quot;,&quot;SecondaryFileExtension&quot;,&quot;DisplayAuthor&quot;,&quot;NewsPageSummary&quot;,&quot;NewsPageRollupImage&quot;,&quot;NewsArticlePageDate&quot;,&quot;NewsPageImage&quot;]" HitHighlightedPropertiesJson="[&quot;Title&quot;,&quot;Path&quot;,&quot;Author&quot;,&quot;SectionNames&quot;,&quot;SiteDescription&quot;]" AvailableSortsJson="null" ShowBestBets="False" ShowPersonalFavorites="False" ShowDefinitions="False" ShowDidYouMean="False" PreloadedItemTemplateIdsJson="null" QueryGroupName="Default" RenderTemplateId="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/SFW_ServiceNewsWP_Content_List.js" StatesJson="{}" ServerIncludeScriptsJson="null" Title="Content Search" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="FirstZone" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_9576a00b_b01a_4206_b236_d36e7d1ccc20" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{9576A00B-B01A-4206-B236-D36E7D1CCC20}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></spsswc:ContentBySearchWebPart>

   <WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{12518184-ED0D-4012-BD2B-20155B25C3BD}" >
   <WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
   <Title>View More Link</Title>
   <FrameType>None</FrameType>
   <Description />
   <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
   <PartOrder>4</PartOrder>
   <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
   <Height />
   <Width />
   <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
   <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
   <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
   <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
   <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
   <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
   <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
   <DetailLink />
   <HelpLink />
   <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
   <Dir>Default</Dir>
   <PartImageSmall />
   <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
   <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
   <IsIncludedFilter />
   <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
   <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
   <ID>g_e3854598-cb85-4646-bb74-888577036873</ID>
   <ContentLink  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
   <Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><!          [CDATA[<div id="dvViewMore"></div>]]></Content>
  <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"   />
  </WebPart>
  </WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
  </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Please do the needful.

Comment: If there is HTML issue making it float left and right, this can fix: http://pastebin.com/ih0Q9WLX